# How to change DPI settings for system apps on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I faced a problem with blurry apps on windows 10. For external programs, I changed DPI settings in Properties of the app -> Compatibility -> Change high DPI settings. But all system apps remain a little blurry. For the note, when I change the scale of my display from 150% to 100%, it doesn't look blurry anymore. Any thoughts on how to fix it? Btw type of the machine: **Ideapad 5-14ARE05 Laptop - Type 81YM**

Comment: Doesn't happen here - please give an example of such an app.

Comment: Windows defender firewall, for example. @harrymc

Comment: Set for native resolution of your Ideapad and check.

Comment: Nope, doesn't happen. Almost all Windows apps are very good on scaling. If you don't have an idea on what's wrong, do [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade.